# Swift - Variable used within its own initial value

Tags: swift

```
func presentLoggedInScreen() {
    let stroyboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let logginedInVCViewController:LogginedInVCViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LogginedInVCViewController" as! LogginedInVCViewController,
    self.present(logginedInVCViewController, animated: true, completion: nil))
}
```

How can I avoid this error?

> variable used within its own initial value

Comment: Why the `,` after `as! LogginedInVCViewController`?

Comment: it says to put it or else I get an error

Comment: Use this `let logginedInVCViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LogginedInVCViewController") as! LogginedInVCViewController` and remove `,`

Comment: still get the same error

Comment: Can you show the updated code that you tried?

Comment: Double-check your parentheses.

Comment: You should accept the answer of @dhin as that helped you , dont post the same answer

Comment: @Adeel oh right, you aren't closing the `)` at that point; **that** is the problem.

Comment: @NicolasMiari No, the problem is that there is an extra `)` at the end of the `self.present` line. It needs to be removed, not closed.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, but shouldn't it be `..."LogginedInVCViewController") as! LogginedInVCViewController...` instead of LogginedInVCViewController" as! LogginedInVCViewController, ...` to begin width?

Comment: @NicolasMiari Ah yes. I missed that. There is the correct number of parentheses. The last one is just in the wrong place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
func presentLoggedInScreen() {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    if let logginedInVCViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LogginedInVCViewController") as? LogginedInVCViewController {
        self.present(logginedInVCViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Use optional binding and whats causing your error is the **,** and extra **)**
 
Sometimes the intellisense of XCode doesnt work properly, so try to analyze the problem first :)

Comment: You should also mention what is the problem in original code and then give your solution , that will be more helpful for readers

Comment: this is my first post ever, thanks for the advice I will keep that in mind

Comment: The `,` is only half the problem. The other half was the extra `)` at the end of the next line. And there is no need for the `if let`. You want to force-unwrap in this case. You want the app to crash if you get the wrong class from the storyboard because it is a serious bug that needs to be fixed.